Cryptopals 2-11: ECB/CBC Detection Oracle is it possible to be completely accurate?
I wrote my oracle so any identical blocks will cause it to classify as ECB, and no collisions means CBC. If I encrypt text that is highly repetitive (will cause obvious collisions in ECB mode), my oracle works flawlessly.
When using a substring of an old term paper, I found that using less than ~3k characters, the oracle completely breaks down and always predicts CBC (seems like no collisions due to no repeating blocks?).  Above ~8500, it again works with 100% accuracy.  Does this seem reasonable? Does it meet the intent of the exercise?  Would this also break down for (perhaps unrealistically) large amounts of text as well, where CBC would yield collisions? Am I approaching the problem wrong?

Seems logical to me, presuming AES the chance of related gotcha is relatively low. Even if text is repeated it just be repeated at the same location and filling a full 16 byte block. You can chat and use UTF16 I suppose.

The efficiency of the test will be very strongly dependent on your plaintext model, which is likely to vary considerably from application to application. In cryptographic terms you are interested in the index of coincidence of the plaintext when considered as an alphabet of size $2^B$ where $B$ is the block size (e.g. 128 for AES). A similar concept is collision entropy.
For your term paper, the collision entropy is likely quite high, particularly if certain concepts/terms/cliches recur. I don't know of any reference to the collision entropy of written English, but there has been some work on the [collision entropy of spoken English]https://aclanthology.org/2021.emnlp-main.653.pdf).
If we take a less structured, but possibly appropriate model, we can consider encrypting printable ASCII characters generated independently and uniformly at random. 16 such characters would make a block, so that there are $95\times 16=1520\approx 2^{10.57}$ possible blocks, so we have a goodish chance to see a collision after 40 or so blocks (perhaps 4000 or so characters).
However, for unstructured data, the two modes are indistinguishable. If we encrypt random 128-bit values selected independently and uniformly, then the collision rate is the same for both ECB and CBC.
More interestingly still, there are examples of structured data where the collision rate for ECB is less than the collision rate for CBC. One can consider the effect of encrypting a 128-bit counter. ECB mode will collide precisely on blocks that are a multiple of $2^{128}$ apart, where as (we strongly believe) CBC will have the collision rate of random data (so we might see a collision in around $2^{64}$ blocks).
Looking at the exercise, although it is not clear, I suspect that the authors are not looking for anything as sophisticated as collisions described above. Instead

 Consider basing your decision on how much longer than the plaintext the ciphertext is. Remembering that CBC mode has an IV. Alternatively, treating the exercise as an unconstrained chosen plaintext attack, we can choose extremes of structure. Consider the effect of choosing a single repeated character as input for various levels of repetition.


Very informative.  I don't think your spoiler is a spoiler, because I don't think it fits the bill - this would be because of a padding difference between ECB and CBC right? But  the "black box" in the exercise will append a random number of bytes to the plaintext.

Also, 2^64 is an unrealistic amount of data (at least for this exercise), and it appears that in the next few challenges, we make use of repeated text, so maybe the "single collision" or more is sufficient for these purposes (although the collision rate vs expectation would allow you to assign a probability of which mode is being used - too sophisticated for this challenge as you noted)
